# Styling a Single Tkinter Notebook Tab

Tags: python, tkinter, tabs, styles

I would like to change the foreground text colour of one Notebook tab to be different from the rest of the tabs as defined by the style created below. As noted I would have expected to get a red font for Tab B, but I am not sure what to style to get this one tab styled. Can someone tell me please what attribute I should change? Thank you very much.

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('%dx%d+0+0' %(200,200))
# Style  # /68485915/
style = ttk.Style()
style.theme_use("default")

# Notebook Style
style.configure('TNotebook', background='white')
style.configure('TNotebook.Tab', background='white', foreground='black')
style.map('TNotebook.Tab',background=[("selected",'green')])
style.configure('Red.TNotebook.Tab', foreground = 'red')

# Create Notebook and Frames
Book = ttk.Notebook(root)

aFrame = ttk.Frame(Book)

# I apply the Red tab style to this frame, but the tab does not change from the style created above
# I am not sure what the relationship between the frame and the tab which is part of the notebook
bFrame = ttk.Frame(Book, style='Red.TNotebook.Tab') #/18855943/

# Pack
aFrame.pack(fill = tk.BOTH, expand = True)
bFrame.pack(fill = tk.BOTH, expand = True)
Book.pack(fill = tk.BOTH, expand = True)

# Add Tabs
Book.add(aFrame, text = 'A')
Book.add(bFrame, text = 'B')

root.mainloop()
```

I looked at the following questions, but none seemed to answer my problem:

- [Is there a way to keep two notebooks with different tab style in tkinter using python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62085711/is-there-a-way-to-keep-two-notebooks-with-different-tab-style-in-tkinter-using-p)
- [Can we use more than 1 style for ttk.Notebook (tkinter), such as "tab.TNotebook" and "background.TNotebook"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65181261/can-we-use-more-than-1-style-for-ttk-notebook-tkinter-such-as-tab-tnotebook)
- [Tkinter ttk see custom theme settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65461962/tkinter-ttk-see-custom-theme-settings)
- [ttk styling "TNotebook.Tab" background and borderwidth not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22389198/ttk-styling-tnotebook-tab-background-and-borderwidth-not-working)
- [Change the color of the Tabcontrol (background, tab, scrollbar)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71330576/change-the-color-of-the-tabcontrol-background-tab-scrollbar),
- [Can we use more than 1 style for ttk.Notebook (tkinter), such as "tab.TNotebook" and "background.TNotebook"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65181261/can-we-use-more-than-1-style-for-ttk-notebook-tkinter-such-as-tab-tnotebook)

Comment: There was a similar question but for the background color https://stackoverflow.com/a/72774960/6415268

Answer (score 1):

> I would like to change the foreground text colour of one Notebook tab
> to be different from the rest of the tabs as defined by the style
> created below

- Use `yummy` instead of `default`.
- Add two constant for green and red.
- Add `style.theme_create`
- Use `style.theme_use("yummy")`
- Comment it out `style.configure`

Snippet modified your script:

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('%dx%d+0+0' %(200,200))
# Style  # 68485915
style = ttk.Style()
 
COLOR_GREEN = "#26d663"
COLOR_RED = "#dd0202"

style.theme_create("yummy", parent="alt", settings={
    "TNotebook": {"configure": {"tabmargins": [2, 5, 2, 0] } },
    "TNotebook.Tab": {
    "configure": {"padding": [5, 1], "background": COLOR_GREEN},
    "map":       {"background": [("selected", COLOR_RED)],
    "expand": [("selected", [1, 1, 1, 0])] } } } )

style.theme_use("yummy")

 
# Create Notebook and Frames
Book = ttk.Notebook(root)

aFrame = ttk.Frame(Book)
Book.add(aFrame, text = 'A')
bFrame = ttk.Frame(Book) #/18855943/
Book.add(bFrame, text = 'B')
Book.pack(fill = tk.BOTH, expand = True)
  

root.mainloop()
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Thanks...that's useful code. I wanted to change the Tab colour of individual tabs though.